# posting multipart form to itself cannot get file name

Tags: jquery, forms, post, file-upload

I am posting a form to itself with jquery which has a file upload in it. I cannot get the file name, i keep getting userfile is not set... when trying to capture the file name

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#chmail").validate({
debug: false,
submitHandler: function(form) {
$.post('new_mail.php', $("#chmail").serialize(), function(data) {
$('#mainBody').html(data);
$("#mainBody").find("script").each(function(i) {
eval($(this).text());
});
});
}
});
});

if (isset($_FILES["userfile"]["name"])) {
echo $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
}


<form method="post" action="" id="chmail" name="chmail" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile" />
<button type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)
Many thanks

Comment: File upload is not possible via Ajax call. Read more [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: found an answer that works great

Comment: Sorry not sure how to put code into a comment       IFrame set up
    '<iframe name="my-iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>'

Form set up
    '<form method="post" id="chmail" name="chmail" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process_mail.php" target="my-iframe">'

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

St up the iframe on your page. In the form set the target as the iframe and set the action to call the script for your uploaded files. No other scripts needed

```
<iframe name="my-iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>


<form method="post" id="chmail" name="chmail" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process_mail.php" target="my-iframe">
```